# Why cygwin for android NDK

Tags: android

New to android NDK, I have followed tutorial mentioned in the post to learn about NDK

[Android NDK tutorial/guide for beginners.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7899740/android-ndk-tutorial-guide-for-beginners)

The tutorial asks for installing Cygwin to build ndk based android app.

I could run ndk-build from my windows command line tool and still produces native .so files.

I don't understand why cygwin is needed ?

Comment: It's not entirely clear that it is needed, and may at times introduce some complications.  However, those used to working on unix-like operating systems may have limited interest in dealing with window's uniqueness, and so may habitually reach for cygwin in order to be able to use most of their usual methods.

Answer (score 0):

Because you need to build Linux(android specifically) binaries not windows x86/64 binaries. Cygwin is a Linux environment that runs in windows, this allows for cross compiling Linux binaries on windows.

Comment: the cross compiler (ported on windows gcc.exe ) comes with NDK to build linux binaries from windows. I can compile android linux code from windows command line rather than cygwin.

Comment: Cygwin is NOT a linux environment.  It is a unix-like environment.  The build tools that come with cygwin build windows binaries, either linked against a cygwin DLL or stand alone.  To build for linux, you would need a cross compiler.  The android NDK is itself a cross compiler, targeting the rather unusual flavor of linux that is Android.